# Can I say "I want to pay my owe"

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes I want to say because I owe you, I want to pay my owe with money.
Can I say "pay my owe" and is it a correct collocation?

Comment: ***owe*** is a verb form only. The noun form is [**owings**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/owings) (plural only) (rare) *- That which is owed; debt.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use "owe" like that, as a noun. You could say "I want to pay you what I owe you", using "owe" as a verb.

Comment: Or: "I want to pay my debt." ... "I want to pay my bill."